# Avoid ANR on SCREEN_ON using Handler Thread

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-handler, android-anr-dialog

Getting ANR executing a blocking/heavy call for Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON. Below is the code

```
    private static BroadcastReceiver mScreenOnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {              
                // Blocking operation
        }
    }
}
```

To avoid ANR, I am planning to move the Blocking operation inside worker thread. Will the below code help in avoiding the ANR?

```
private static BroadcastReceiver mScreenOnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {              
                new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Blocking operation
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. `BroadcastReceiver`s are short-lived. There is no guarantee that the OS process hosting your `BroadcastReceiver` will live long enough to execute this code. Not only that, but you would be running this code on the Main (UI) thread, which you cannot block (your `Runnable` will not run in a "worker thread", it will run in the Main (UI) thread).

Your `BroadcastReceiver` should start a `Service`, which can run a background (worker) thread which can perform your blocking operation. Or you may be able to use `JobScheduler` to schedule this operation (if it is suitable for your purpose).